# How to close newly opened window in Jmeter webdriver Sampler.?

Tags: selenium, automation, jmeter, webdriver

I have automated some actions in JMeter webdriver sampler, in a scenario I am moving to new window, but I am not able to close the newly opened window in that. 
`WDS.browser.close()` does not work there. How can I close only the new window and work with parent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var handles = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles() 
var iterator = handles.iterator()
var currentHandle = WDS.browser.getWindowHandle()
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    var handle = iterator.next() 
    if (handle != currentHandle) {
        WDS.browser.switchTo().window(handle)
        WDS.browser.close()
    }
}
WDS.browser.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

References:

- [How To Work with Multiple Windows](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Answer (score 0):

What I do (in python though) is switch handles, close the current window, then switch back. Perhaps it can serve as inspiration for you problem :

```
def close_additional_tabs(self):
        self.cfg.logger.info("[TEARDOWN] Close open tabs and switch to original frame.")
        while len(self.webdriver.window_handles) > 1:
            self.webdriver.switch_to_window(self.webdriver.window_handles[-1])
            self.webdriver.close()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.webdriver.switch_to_window(self.webdriver.window_handles[-1])
```

This is for tabs but it works with windows as well.

Comment: This is not possible in case of JMeter webdriver sampler. there it is BeanShell language, I am familiar with handling windows in IDE and all but inside jmeter webdriver sampler How can I do this using BeanShell language.